# Where condition in Entity Framework dose not work correctly

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

I have `Article` and `ArticleTranslation` tables.

When I use this query, it does not retrieve data:

```
model.CategoryList = await db.ArticleCategoryTranslations
            .Where(x => x.LangId == lang.Id && 
            x.ArticleCategory.IsActive.Value == true && 
            x.ArticleCategory.IsDelete.Value == false)
            .Select(x => new ddl { Id = x.RecordId.Value, Name = x.Title }).ToListAsync();
```

but when I use this it works, Tell me what problem in the first code

```
model.CategoryList = await db.ArticleCategoryTranslations
            .Where(x => x.LangId == lang.Id && 
            db.ArticleCategorys.Where(u => u.Id == x.RecordId).FirstOrDefault().IsActive == true &&
            db.ArticleCategorys.Where(u => u.Id == x.RecordId).FirstOrDefault().IsDelete == false 
            )
            .Select(x => new ddl { Id = x.RecordId.Value, Name = x.Title }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Is `ArticleCategory` lazy loaded? Did you mark this navigation property as `virtual` so lazy loading actually works?

Comment: Did you set up the relationships properly? Both in db and in your model?

Comment: Those are 2 very different queries. The first appears to look at a singular instance of ArticleCategory affiliated with a ArticleCategoryTranslations. The second appears to be looking at your entire ArticleCategorys lookup table - probably not what you intend. You need to show the models involved and make sure there is actual matching data. Logging your SQL can help with this.

Comment: Is `RecordId` a FK in `ArticleCategoryTranslations` for `ArticleCategory`? For first query, it check the `IsActive` and `IsDelete` by FK between `ArticleCategoryTranslations` and `ArticleCategory`. For second query, it check them by `u => u.Id == x.RecordId`. Share us the defination for the two models.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the properties on your model objects look like but comparing both code snippets I see in the successful one the `IsActive` and `IsDelete` properties don't call the Value property i.e `IsActive.Value` and `IsDelete.Value`. 
So your code should look like

```
    model.CategoryList = await db.ArticleCategoryTranslations
        .Where(x => x.LangId == lang.Id && 
        x.ArticleCategory.IsActive == true && 
        x.ArticleCategory.IsDelete == false)
        .Select(x => new ddl { Id = x.RecordId.Value, Name = x.Title }).ToListAsync();
```

This assumes you have your navigation properties done right.

Comment: No, the successful one works because it is not looking at the child table - it is looking at the whole lookup table.